# how to fix view under navigation bar swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios-autolayout

i make popup using EzPopup library, i get problem when i put popup under navigation bar.
this my code

```
@IBAction func showTopRightButton(_ sender: Any){
    guard let pickerVC = pickerVC else { return }

    pickerVC.delegate = self

    let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: pickerVC, position: .topRight(CGPoint(x: 0, y: navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height+20)), popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

    popupVC.cornerRadius = 5
    present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

i got a problem like my image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGDga.png)

how to make same in iphone x and iphone x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iPhone X portrait mode, the status bar is taller — 44 pts, not 20 pts

You need to add the statusBar Frame height also. Try below code:

```
//1.0 Get the Top bar height
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)

let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: pickerVC, position: .topRight(CGPoint(x: 0, y: topBarHeight)), popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)
```

You can read more information on UILayout [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/).